# mute microphone programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to mute my microphone programmatically ,i tried the following code but it is use full.

```
micro_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                if (audioManager.isMicrophoneMute() == false) {
                    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);

                } else {
                    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);

                }
```

Comment: Did u found the solution ? @venkatesh

Answer (score 7):

Check if you added permission 
    android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"  , it is mandatory for changing audio settings

Comment: Yes alex,i've added those permissions

Comment: What i exactly want is when i run this app and make a call ,my mic should be mute

Comment: Try this const
AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION

Comment: Do I need to `requestPermissions` this for Marshmallow and above?